# Create an Abaqus field output with some invalid data

Tags: python, abaqus, abaqus-odb

I want to add a output field to an odb. Not all the values are available and I would like to input an "invalid data". What should I pass?
I tried nan, string, 1/0, which do not work

The basic coding I used  to add a field output is:

```
instance = odb.rootAssembly.instances['nameOfYourInstance']

field_output = odb.steps['stepName'].frames[frameId].FieldOutput(
    name='DefineTheName', description='WhatItRepresents',
    type=SCALAR # or whatever other type you need
)

field.addData(
    position=NODAL, instance=instance, labels=your_node_labels,
    data=your_data
)
```

I want to pass an invalid data in a specific place in your_data

Comment: You keep only those nodes in `your_node_labels` variable for which you have data in `your_data` variable. For Ex. Let's say, you have the data for `your_node_labels=[1, 10, 12, 14, 50]` nodes only and corresponding values are `your_data=[10.0, 1.0, 2.2, 3.3, 15.5]` something like this. Here, for node `1` you have `10.0` value, for node `10` you have `1.0` value and so on. In this case, no data is written for the nodes other than the nodes in `your_node_labels` variable, hence no contour will be shown for those nodes.

Comment: Thank you @SatishThorat :-) So obvious that I did not even think about that!! Maybe you can make it an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Great! I have added it as answer. Kindly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep only those nodes in `your_node_labels` variable for which you have data in `your_data` variable. 
For Ex. Let's say, you have the data for `your_node_labels=[1, 10, 12, 14, 50]` nodes only and corresponding values are `your_data=[10.0, 1.0, 2.2, 3.3, 15.5]` something like this. Here, for node `1` you have value `10.0`, for node `10` you have value `1.0` and so on. In this case, no data is written for the nodes other than the nodes in `your_node_labels` variable, hence no contour will be shown for those nodes.